# Perl: Recursively rename all files and directories

Tags: linux, perl

I need to recursively rename every file and directory. I convert spaces to underscores and make all file/directory names to lowercase. How can I make the following script rename all files in one run? Currently the script needs to be run several times before all the files/directories are converted. The code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find;

$input_file_dir = $ARGV[0];

sub process_file {
        $clean_name=lc($_);
        $clean_name=~s/\s/_/g;
        rename($_,$clean_name);
        print "file/dir name: $clean_name\n";
}
find(\&process_file, $input_file_dir);
```

Comment: What should happen if "Some Filename" and "some_filename" both exist in the same directory?  And for non-empty directories "Some Dir" and "some_dir" with the same parent?

Comment: Do you know that perl comes with a rename(3) script?

Comment: @Pasi: it is "prename". For some reason, as usual, Debian decided to break things around and rename it to "rename", replacing the original rename from userlinux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to specify `bydepth => 1` in the options you pass to find or call `finddepth`. From [perldoc File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find):

> `bydepth`
>
> Reports the name of a directory only AFTER all its entries have been reported. Entry point `finddepth()` is a shortcut for specifying `{ bydepth => 1 }` in the first argument of `find()`.

However, **you still need to decide how to deal with naming clashes because rename will clobber the target if the target exists**.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use File::Find;

finddepth(\&process_file, $_) for @ARGV;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are open to other approaches, here's a Python solution

```
import os
for R,DIR,FILES in os.walk("/mypath",topdown=False):
    for file in FILES:
        newfile=file.lower().replace(" ","_")
        new_file_name=os.path.join(R,newfile)
        os.rename( os.path.join(R,file) , new_file_name)
    for dir in DIR:
        newdir=dir.lower().replace(" ","_")
        new_dir_name=os.path.join(R,newdir)
        os.rename( os.path.join(R,dir) , new_dir_name)
```

Comment: I used the above script and I see that it works perfectly fine.  Thanks for sharing this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can rename files before traversing through a directory.

```
find({
        preprocess => sub {
            for (@_) {
                my $oldname = $_;
                $_ = lc;
                s/\s/_/g;
                rename $oldname => $_;
            }
            return @_;
        },
        wanted => sub {
            print "$File::Find::name was already renamed\n";
        },
    },
    @dirs
);
```

Or you could delay the renames until after traversal has occurred.

```
finddepth(sub {
        print "in $File::Find::dir, renaming $_\n";
        my $newname = lc;
        $newname =~ s/\s/_/g;
        rename $_ => $newname;
    },
    @dirs
);
```

The problem you are encountering is because

`find` finds directory `"Abc Def"`
`find` calls `wanted("Abc Def")`
    `rename "Abc Def" => "abc_def"`
`find` tries to enter `"Abc Def"`, which does not exist anymore
    so everything underneath does not get processed