# How to rename directories recursively

Tags: perl

I want to rename directories recursively using File::Find::Rule, eg. remove extra spaces in each found but as I understand the module doesn't do finddepth and renames only one. Is there a way to do that. Thanks.

```
use autodie;
use strict ;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = 'D:/Test';

my @fd = File::Find::Rule->directory
->in( $dir );

for my $fd ( @fd ) {
    my $new = $fd;

    $new =~ s/\s\s+/ /g;

    print "$new\n";

    rename $fd, $new;   
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl: Recursively rename all files and directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557199/perl-recursively-rename-all-files-and-directories)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to process the deeper results first, so process the list in reverse. You can only rename the leaf part of the path; you'll get to the more shallow parts later.

```
use Path::Class qw( dir );

for ( reverse @fd ) {
   my $dir = dir($_);
   my $parent = $dir->parent;
   my $old_leaf = my $new_leaf = $dir->dir_list(-1);

   $new_leaf =~ s/\s+/ /g;

   if ($new_leaf ne $old_leaf) {
      my $old_file = $parent->dir($old_leaf);
      my $new_file = $parent->dir($new_leaf);

      # Prevent accidental deletion of files.
      if (-e $new_file) {
         warn("$new_file already exists\n");
         next;
      }

      rename($old_file, $new_file);
   }
}
```

---

**Answer to original question:**

I don't see how FFR comes into play.

```
rename 'Test1/Test2/Test3', 'Test1/Test2/Dir3';
rename 'Test1/Test2', 'Test1/Dir2';
rename 'Test1', 'Dir1';
```

For arbitrary paths,

```
use Path::Class qw( dir );

my @parts1 = dir('Test1/Test2/Test3')->dir_list();
my @parts2 = dir('Dir1/Dir2/Dir3'   )->dir_list();

die if @parts1 != @parts2;

for (reverse 0..$#parts1) {
   my $path1 = dir(@parts1[ 0..$_ ]);
   my $path2 = dir(@parts2[ 0..$_ ]);
   rename($path1, $path2);
}
```

Or maybe you want to rename all Test1 to Dir1, Test2 to Dir2, and Test3 to Dir3, process the list in reverse order.

```
my %map = (
   'Test1' => 'Dir1',
   'Test2' => 'Dir2',
   'Test3' => 'Dir3',
);

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %map;

for ( reverse @fd ) {
   my $o = $_;
   my $n = $_;
   $n =~ s{/\K($pat)\z}{$map{$1}};
   if ($n ne $o) {
      if (-e $n) {
         warn("$n already exists\n");
         next;
      }

      rename($o, $n);
   }
}
```

Comment: ikegami, many thanks for your suggestion but I'm looking for a more general solution. i just realized that my example is misleading and i'm very sorry for that. I'm writing a much bigger script for organizing files and directories based on File::Find::Rule and at one moment realized that I can't mass rename directories recursively - let's say uppercase or lowercase, or replacing some characters in each found. I need advice if this is possible with this module.

Comment: @thebourneid, Well, if you didn't define the problem accurately, why don't you start by addressing that?

Comment: I edited my post and apologize again. Serves me right if I don't get an answer. I will test your suggestions. Many thanks.

Comment: @thebourneid, The answer is still the same. Process the list in reverse. You'll get the deeper results first that way. Added code to node.

Comment: You've been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have a module for doing actions recursively in a directory tree. It didn't have the ability to act on the directories themselves though, so it took a little updating. I have uploaded version 0.03 of my [`File::chdir::WalkDir`](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3achdir%3a%3aWalkDir), <s>but until it shows up,</s> it can be installed from its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jberger/File-chdir-WalkDir), and now available using your fav CPAN utility. This script would then remove spaces from directory names inside the base directory 'Test' relative to the working directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::chdir::WalkDir 0.030;
use File::Copy;

my $job = sub {
  my ($name, $in_dir) = @_;

  #ONLY act on directories
  return 0 unless (-d $name);

  my $new_name = $name;
  if ($new_name =~ s/\s+/ /g) {
    move($name, $new_name); 
  }

};

walkdir( 'Test', $job, {'act_on_directories' => 1} );
```